# Using celery worker in Heroku causes timeout

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I'm using Heroku for my Django project which runs on the `daphne` server. And also I have a celery worker to run tasks parallelly to reduce response time.

Below is my Procfile

```
web: daphne myproject.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v 0
worker: celery worker -A myproject --loglevel=debug --concurrency=8
```

**Scenario:** I need to generate a statement using the last 24 months of balance data.

For that, I have two endpoints

> - GET BALANCE - Fetch the 24 months of balance ( **each month is considered as a task** and 24 tasks are run using celery worker )
> - GENERATE STATEMENT - Generate the statement for 24 months of data ( This API is called immediately after GET BALANCE API )

If I test for a single company it takes 15 - 20 seconds for the first API. But if I test for 2 or more companies (using load testing) it first company alone passes and others are failed due to **HEROKU 30 Seconds Timeout problem**

For example for 5 companies:

- C1 - takes 15 seconds to complete - **Pass**
- C2 - takes 27 seconds to complete - **Pass**
- C3 - takes 43 seconds to complete - **Timeout**
- C4 - takes 48 seconds to complete - **Timeout**
- C5 - takes 55 seconds to complete - **Timeout**

I think the issue is because of the JOB queuing and HEROKU Timeout. But I can't send the response to the client in **GET BALANCE** call before the jobs getting completed because on the next second I need to generate the statement.

Also, I have tried by increasing the worker limit but it works for up to 2 or 3 companies not more than that.

Please suggest me some way so i can get rid of the timeout issue

Comment: You'll need to show some code. Worker dynos shouldn't timeout. Are you sure you're actually executing the task in the worker rather than directly in the view?

Comment: Yes I'm executing the tasks in worker and wait for tasks to complete to send back response to client

Comment: But the whole point of workers is so that you *don't* need to wait. Otherwise you might as well do it in the view.

Comment: But my scenario is like once the worker based call get completed I need to hit another API to generate statement

Comment: If i don't wait for tasks to complete then the statement generated in the next call may be not correct.

Comment: Then the statement generation should *itself* be a Celery task, which is triggered when the others have completed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200556/discussion-between-muthu-kumar-and-daniel-roseman).